# DEADLINE_EXCEEDED exception to BigQuery insert request

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I observed this issue today in which BigQuery returned DEADLINE_EXCEEDED exception to the streaming insert request. The error response is as follows:

`{"insertErrors":[{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"bigtable::Deadline missed: /BTI_TabletServer.Apply to 10.73.63.65:25806 : DEADLINE_EXCEEDED","location":"","message":"","reason":"timeout"}],"index":5},{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"bigtable::Deadline missed: /BTI_TabletServer.Apply to 10.73.63.65:25806 : DEADLINE_EXCEEDED","location":"","message":"","reason":"timeout"}],"index":6}],"kind":"bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse"}`

I got this error even after 3 - 4 retry attempts. The number of rows that I tried to insert is about 100 and the size of each row is very less (less than 10kB). Can anyone please let me know if this is a client side issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SLA for BigQuery is 99.99%. It's not 100% (just like all other clouds/services). That means you're going to get transient errors like this from time to time - especially with streaming. Thus, you need to consider this in your app/code/design and use exponential back-off-and-retry techniques together with some kind of queue (e.g. Pub/Sub, SQS) which you consume and process somewhere else.